# Assigning OpenCV Mat object causes a memory leak

Tags: android, c++, opencv, memory-leaks, android-ndk

I want to assign frame (`Mat` object) from function parameter into object variable, as shown in the code below. This function should be called may times (for each frame from the video camera), but this line

```
this->nFrame = frame;
```

causes a memory leak (when commented there is no error!).

**NOTE**
The function `setCurrentFrame` is called inside `JNI` function, where this `JNI` function is called every time I want to process the frame from the video camera.

The `JNI` function is like:

```
JNIEXPORT jbyteArray JNICALL Java_com_adhamenaya_Native_run(JNIEnv * env,
        jobject obj, jstring faceCascadeFile, jstring noseCascadeFile,
        jstring landmarks, jlong frame) {

    MyClass gsys;
    cv::Mat& inFrame = *(cv::Mat*) frame;
    gsys.setCurrentFrame(inFrame);


    // SOME PROCESSING FOR THE FRAME 


    inFrame.release();
    gsys.release();

    ......
    ......
}
```

**The code for C++ function (setCurrentFrame)**

```
void MyClass::setCurrentFrame(cv::Mat& frame) {
    cv::Size2d imgRes;
    float resRatio;

    if (frame.cols > frame.rows) {
        //landscape
        imgRes.width = 640.0f;
        resRatio = frame.cols / 640.0f;
        imgRes.height = floor(frame.rows / resRatio);
    } else {
        //portrait
        imgRes.height = 640.0f;
        resRatio = frame.rows / 640.0f;
        imgRes.width = floor(frame.cols / resRatio);
    }

    //save scaled height, width for further use
    this->frameWidth = nFrame.cols;
    this->frameHeight = nFrame.rows;

    //set frame and increment frameCount
    this->nFrame = frame;
    this->frameCount++;
}
```

Kindly, can you help me to solve this problem ? I tried to release the frame by calling :

```
void MyClass::release(void) {
    this->nFrame = cv::Mat();
}
```

nothing happened, even like this:

```
void MyClass::release(void) {
    this->nFrame.release();
}
```

Still the same error!

**Edit**

**MyClass.h**

```
class MyClass {

public:
    cv::Mat nFrame;

    MyClass ();
    ~MyClass ();
    void release (void);
    void setCurrentFrame(cv::Mat& frame);

};
```

Comment: @Miki I have edited the question.

Comment: which tool do you use to detect leaks?

Comment: Using the android **adb**. I have little information about the leak , this message `10-18 21:57:59.399: A/libc(15001): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x80000 in tid 15113 (Thread-8815)` @RonaldoMessi

Answer (score 0):

In the jni file, the order of releasing frame objects can be erroneus:

```
inFrame.release();
gsys.release();
```

should be

```
gsys.release();
inFrame.release();
```

because when you free source frame then frame reference in gsys is invalidated.

Comment: Do you mean, it should be `gsys.release(); inFrame.release();` ?

Comment: Thanks, I can't try it now. I will later, and back to answer ASAP.